# Apply changes after deploying an ASP.Net MVC 5 website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm currently developing an ASP.Net MVC 5. The problem is, I have always coded the websites and handed them over to other people who managed the deployment and maintenance. I have never been on the other side of the production and now I have to be. I have read some articles for ASP.Net MVC 3 but since I am creating this project with MVC 5, I was wondering what I should do in situations where the models need some changes. For instance:

- I rename field or column
- Add another field to the model with acceptable default values (maybe even null)
- Remove a field
- ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to generate the script needed to update your database. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#script) post for more information. Basically it says:

> Run the Update-Database command but this time specify the –Script flag
>   so that changes are written to a script rather than applied.

Open your package manager console (Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console), target your migrations project, and run "Update-Database -Script".

Then take the script and run it against your production / staging / testing / whatever environment.

Comment: Awesome. Just one question. Currently, I'm using the `Database.SetInitializer(new Ghazanet.Infrastructure.CustomInitializer());` to re-initialize the DB whenever I change the models. When should enable and build theinitial migration?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848746/using-entity-framework-code-first-migrations-in-production and the related links in that post for more information