# How can I call Entity Framework commands via code?

Tags: entity-framework

I can run the following from the package manager console

```
update-database -targetmigration:0 -force
```

How can I do the same thing via C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Database Initializer you can use to achieve the migration to latest version on startup (or better, the dbinitializer will kick in on first db access), the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`, you use it like that:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ObjectContext>(
    new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ObjectContext, Configuration>());
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10850935/1551

You can also just set automigrations to true, and I'm sure you can configure force to happen also if necesary, though it probably will not by default.