# Manually updating database, EF complians model backing the context has changed

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

When I run my application it says the model backing my context has changed since the database was created.

I added a field to my model like:

```
public int? LocationId {get;set;}
```

I added an `int` column to the database, and it is nullable.

I understand the database has that `_migrationsHistory` table that is now not in sync.

What I have been doing so far in QA is just dropping all the tables and then running the application which just re-creates the database automatically for me.

Now I want to keep the data in the table, how can I fix this issue?

I added the column so it should work, but when it performs the validation during startup if fails.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use [**Code-First Migrations**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj591621.aspx) (EF 4.3 and later)

This would allow you to generate migration files based on changes to the model via the Package Manager Console.

you can generate a migration file by using `add-migration <name>`, make changes to it if required and use `update-database` to manually update.

You can also roll-back to any migration point if you inadvertently break something.

Comment: Thanks I did that, but in production I cannot connect to the database from my laptop so will it run the migration during application startup?

Comment: Not by default, but i think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848746/using-entity-framework-code-first-migrations-in-production