# Entity framework Code First database migration for SQL-CE along with Setup

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-migrations

I am using entity framework code first model in a windows form application, I have an existing database in AppData folder and created migration script for it using `Add-Migration`. When I run `Update-Database` from Package Manager Console, the database gets properly updated. But when I create SETUP.exe for the same project and install that setup, changes are not migrated to database.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848746/using-entity-framework-code-first-migrations-in-production

Comment: Database.SetInitializer<ObjectContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ObjectContext, Configuration>()); I am not getting what I need to pass to Configuration parameter. Is it my Configuration class in Migrations folder?

Comment: Yes you add your DatabaseContext and Migration configuration. This wont apply the migrations on installation tho, but instead on first time running. I am not sure if you can apply them during installation.

Comment: Yup, It works! Thanks for comment, it applied migrations on first run, but for now that is enough for me.

Comment: It is working for upgrading database, but if the database doesn't exist then it fails to create. Can you please tell where I might be going wrong.

Comment: Use `CreateIfNotExists` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.createifnotexists(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129044/discussion-between-aniket-bhansali-and-mats391).