# How to update-database for databases hosted on client's server

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

at the moment we have a migration project that will utilize entity framework's migrate.exe and update the database models to match the current object models. The solution works great for data I have immediate access to, meaning locally or any that are on our servers. Not only do I update the models, sometimes I add data to populate the new columns as well. Now I'm coming across some clients that want to host their data locally.

The current strategy that we thought of is to grab a backup of their local database, restore it locally onto our machines and update then restore it back to their servers.

My question is what is the best strategy to use to update databases that are located locally and to populate them.

Comment: Do a google search for "sql server update schema",

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will read on that right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Entity Framework (code first) migrations in production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848746/using-entity-framework-code-first-migrations-in-production)

Comment: @luri Farenzena, it's actually not. That's for production servers meaning you can connect to it via internet, major difference between my post and that post.

Comment: It is not true that production servers are always internet accessible.  It depends on what they are being used for.  The solution in the possible duplicate should work for your situation as well.

Comment: @GrandOpener At the moment that IS the solution I'm currently using. It's part of my migration project. That solution isn't applicable because the client's servers aren't accessible to me directly.

Comment: With the information given thus far, the solution appear to be applicable.  If you modify your software so that it does the migration on startup, then they will automatically get migrated the first time they run the new version of the software.  If that is not possible, can you clarify why?